# Playing of the previous/next song by the buttons in notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-broadcast

I have a player, where when user choose a song, player makes a notification with 3 buttons: previous, play, next. This buttons are needed to choose the songs in background mode. But when I click on this buttons nothing is happened. Here's the code of notification:

```
Intent intentPrev = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intentPrev.setAction(ACTION_PREV);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intentPrev);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentPrev = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentPrev, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intentPlay = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intentPlay.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intentPlay);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentPlay = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentPlay, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intentNext = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        intentNext.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intentNext);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentNext = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentNext, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification).
                setContentTitle(songs.get(songPos).getTitle()).setContentText(songs.get(songPos).getArtist()).
                addAction(R.drawable.previous, "Previous", pendingIntentPrev).addAction(R.drawable.pause, "Pause", pendingIntentPlay).
                addAction(R.drawable.next, "Next", pendingIntentNext);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

And here's the code of Receiver:

```
package asus.example.com.player;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.util.Objects;

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String    ACTION_PREV = "PREVIOUS";
    private final String    ACTION_PLAY = "PLAY";
    private final String    ACTION_NEXT = "NEXT";
    private final MyService service     = new MyService();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), ACTION_PREV)){
            service.playPrev();
        }
        else if (Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), ACTION_NEXT)){
            service.playNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Also I added receiver to Manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".NotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="PREVIOUS"/>
                <action android:name="PLAY"/>
                <action android:name="NEXT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

When I watched in debugger I saw that Receiver class isn't used, but I don't understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you are sending a broadcast immediately with statements like this:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intentNext);
```

And you say you want to start an `Activity` later on:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntentNext = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentNext, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

(Side note: this won't work anyway because in *intentNext*, you specify a class extending from `BroadcastReceiver` not from `Activity`)

It should be `getBroadcast()` not `getActivity()`:

```
Intent intentNext = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
intentNext.setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
PendingIntent pendingIntentNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentNext, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Another thing: you are using '0' as request code (second parameter) in all your `PendingIntent`s. You have to *use different values for the request codes* because two `Intent`s sharing the same request code are considered to be the same `Intent`, so you'd end up with all three notification `Button`s triggering the same action.